# vercel node.js 404 when try to access via URL

Tags: node.js, vercel

I am getting 404 after deploy on vercel.
I have created a vercel.json and add below content as well

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but still getting the same error.

My folder Strucutre - [image]

My Index.js

```
const apis = require("./app/config/api-config");


const PORT = 9697;

apis.app.listen(process.env.PORT || PORT, function() {
    console.log("server connected to port " + PORT);
});
```

I am trying to access it via - `https://example.vercel.app/api/login`

Everything works very well on local machine.

Comment: @pierpy Tried but still facing the same issue.